pymilvus: Failed to create new connection using 03f6034f5bdb454fbf42ffd5c13d5a33
I am trying to make a script which summarizes the text fed it to a model and saves it on milvus.
My project is extracting content from 3 digital textbooks which have at least 300 pages each. This extracted content should be used to create a vector database using MILVUS with RAPTOR indexing.
It should extract the content from the selected textbooks thoroughly, ensuring that all relevant text is captured; then chunk the extracted content into short, contiguous texts of approximately 100 tokens each, preserving sentence boundaries.
The chunked texts should be embedded using SBERT (Sentence-BERT) to create vector representations.
Clustering the embedded chunks using Gaussian Mixture Models (GMMs) with soft clustering, allowing nodes to belong to multiple clusters.
Summarizing the clusters using an LLM (e.g., GPT-3.5-turbo) to create concise representations of the grouped texts.
Re-embedding the summarized texts and recursively applying the clustering and summarization process until a hierarchical tree structure is formed.
The resulting RAPTOR index should capture both high-level and low-level details of the textbooks, enabling efficient retrieval at different levels of granularity.
Store the RAPTOR index in a MILVUS vector database, along with relevant metadata such as the textbook title and page number.
This is my code
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import numpy as np
from pymilvus import MilvusClient, connections, utility, FieldSchema, CollectionSchema, DataType, Collection
from transformers import pipeline

# Initialize models and pipelines
sbert_model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')
summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")

# Connect to Milvus Lite
client = MilvusClient("milvus_demo.db")

def create_milvus_collection(collection_name):
    if utility.has_collection(collection_name):
        utility.drop_collection(collection_name)

    fields = [
        FieldSchema(name="id", dtype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True, auto_id=True),
        FieldSchema(name="embedding", dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=384),
        FieldSchema(name="metadata", dtype=DataType.STRING),
    ]
    schema = CollectionSchema(fields, "Textbook Content Embeddings")
    collection = Collection(name=collection_name, schema=schema)
    collection.create_index("embedding", {"index_type": "IVF_FLAT", "params": {"nlist": 1024}})
    return collection

collection_name = "textbook_embeddings"
collection = create_milvus_collection(collection_name)

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    text = ""
    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)
        text += page.get_text()
    return text

def chunk_text(text, chunk_size=100):
    words = text.split()
    chunks = [" ".join(words[i:i + chunk_size]) for i in range(0, len(words), chunk_size)]
    return chunks

def embed_texts(texts):
    embeddings = sbert_model.encode(texts)
    return embeddings

# Example usage
pdf_paths = ["Introduction_to_Psychology.pdf", "Principles_of_Economics.pdf", "Fundamentals_of_Biology.pdf"]
all_text_chunks = []
all_embeddings = []

for pdf_path in pdf_paths:
    text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)
    chunks = chunk_text(text)
    embeddings = embed_texts(chunks)
    
    all_text_chunks.extend(chunks)
    all_embeddings.extend(embeddings)

# Insert data into Milvus Lite
data = [{"id": i, "vector": all_embeddings[i], "text": all_text_chunks[i], "subject": "textbook"} for i in range(len(all_embeddings))]
res = client.insert(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    data=data
)

# Example search
search_embedding = sbert_model.encode(["Psychology is the scientific study of behavior and mental processes."])
res = client.search(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    data=[search_embedding],
    filter="subject == 'textbook'",
    limit=3,
    output_fields=["text", "subject"],
)
print(res)

# Example query
res = client.query(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    filter="subject == 'textbook'",
    output_fields=["text", "subject"],
)
print(res)

Now I am having this error. I have never worked with Milvus and pymilvus and have zero idea what's happening:
PS F:\text extractor answerer> py .\process_textbooks.py    
Failed to create new connection using: 03f6034f5bdb454fbf42ffd5c13d5a33
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\text extractor answerer\process_textbooks.py", line 12, in <module>
    client = MilvusClient("milvus_demo.db")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymilvus\milvus_client\milvus_client.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._using = self._create_connection(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymilvus\milvus_client\milvus_client.py", line 651, in _create_connection
    raise ex from ex
  File "C:\Users\ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymilvus\milvus_client\milvus_client.py", line 648, in _create_connection
    connections.connect(using, user, password, db_name, token, uri=uri, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ramin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymilvus\orm\connections.py", line 378, in connect 
    from milvus_lite.server_manager import server_manager_instance
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'milvus_lite'


Looks like it doesn't work on Windows https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-lite/issues/175

Stack Overflow homework FAQ

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
